# Why is my activator class adding the files/running the actions I add?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks

I am using the WP Plugin Boilerplate to develop a plugin, but when I activate the plugin, the require files and actions I put inside the `activate()` function are not working. I have tested the class and method by using `die('Plugin error')` and it should this message so I am not sure as to why the the other statements aren't working. There is also no PHP error being thrown.

```
class Wp_Portfolio_Pro_Activator {

    /**
     * Short Description. (use period)
     *
     * Long Description.
     *
     * @since    1.0.0
     */
    public static function activate() {
        // Require Kirki and setting for plugin build on framework.
        self::load_files();

        add_action( 'admin_notices', array( __CLASS__, 'admin_notice' ) );
    }

    public static function admin_notice() {
        $message = '<div class="notice notice-success"><p>';
        $message .= sprintf( __( 'Hello %s!', 'my-plugin' ), '<strong>' . get_current_user_name() . '</strong>' );
        $message .= '</p><p>';
        $message .= __( 'Thank you for downloading WP Portfolio Pro. Edit the setting from the customizer.', 'wp-portfolio-pro' );
        $message .= '</p>';
        $message .= '<a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( 'customize.php?customize_changeset_uuid=' . get_theme_mods_changeset_post_id() ) ) . '"><button>Go to settings</button></a></div>';
        echo $message;
        printf( '<div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">%1$s</div>', $message );
    }

    public static function load_files() {
        // Require Kirki and setting for plugin build on framework.
        require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/kirki/kirki.php';
        require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/wp-portfolio-pro-kirki.php';
    }

}
```

This is the code in the main file that calls the class and runs the activate method:

```
/**
 * The code that runs during plugin activation.
 * This action is documented in includes/class-wp-portfolio-pro-activator.php
 */
function activate_wp_portfolio_pro() {
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-wp-portfolio-pro-activator.php';
    Wp_Portfolio_Pro_Activator::activate();
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_wp_portfolio_pro' );
```

Comment: We can't use `$this->` because they are static so we have to use `self::`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is almost certainly loading those files and adding the notice, but you've misunderstood how PHP works so they're not happening when you expect them to happen.

You need to keep two things in mind with PHP:

1. Admin notices and `require_once` are not persistent across multiple requests. If you want to load a file or display a notice you need to run that code for every request for which you want the notice to appear or the files to be loaded.
2. Your plugin code will run for every page request in the browser, but the activation hook will only run once: when the plugin is activated.

So keep those in mind when you consider the sequence of activating a plugin through the UI:

1. You visit `wp-admin/plugins.php` and click *Activate* on a plugin.
2. You are taken to `/wp-admin/plugins.php?action=activate&plugin=plugin-name.php`, where the plugin is activated.
3. You are redirected back to to `/wp-admin/plugins.php?activate=true`.

Your `activate()` method is *only going to run for step 2*. This means that the framework you're trying to load is only going to load during step 2, and your notice is only going to be during step 2.

So you need to do 2 things:

1. Run `load_files()` on every request. In the WP Plugin Boilerplate there is already a `load_dependencies()` method of the `Plugin_Name` class that seems to be intended for loading files.
2. Run your `add_action()` for `admin_notices` on every request. In the boilerplate the `define_admin_hooks()` method of the `Plugin_Name` class seems the appropriate place for this. In your `admin_notices` method you will need to implement logic to hide the notice if it's been dismissed.

Comment: This helped me so much! Yea I think I misunderstood the activator class. Totally understand the structure more now. I appreciate you help! :)